# Advanced Query with a bit of logic

Tags: ms-access, logic, ms-access-2007

I have an advanced query/report that I need help creating in Access 2007.
The query I need generated is:

```
Employee Last, Employee First, Employee Role, Course Name, StartDate, EndDate, Attended
```

The Logic that I need to handle this is:

1. IF user has attended a course with employeerole = courserole,
   Attended = Yes
2. If user hasn't attended a course with Employeerole = courserole,
   Attended = No
3. If user hasn't attended and there is not a Course with a Matching
   CourseRole, Attended = No Course with that Role

Some additional logic that would be nice would be to add:  Trainer Last to the Select
Logic: if Data isNull, Trainer Last = No Trainer Assigned

It wont let me post a picture of the database. So here is the Tables with Referential Entegrity:

```
Tables:  Fields
Employee: Employee_PK, Employee_Last, Employee_first, Employee_userid   
Role: Role_PK, RoleNAme  
EmployeeRole: EmployeeRole_PK, Employee_ID, Role_ID  
Location: Location_PK, Location  
Course: Course_PK, StartDate, EndDate, CourseName, CourseNotes, Location_ID  
CourseAttendance: CourseAttendance_PK, Course_ID, Employee_ID  
CourseRole: CourseRole_PK, Course_ID, Role_ID  
Trainer: Trainer_PK, TrainerLast, TrainerFirst  
TrainerCourse:Trainer_PK, Trainer_ID, Course_ID
```

So you can see it's normalized and there are multiple Many to Many Tables which are required
PK is for Primary Key, ID is used as Foreign Key. So yes these are ok.

EDIT:
This query was posted in the comments:
I've tried a number of queries.

```
SELECT qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.*, IIf(IsNull([courseattendance_PK]),"No","Yes") AS Attended 
FROM qryEmployeeCoursesForRole 
LEFT JOIN CourseAttendance 
    ON (qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.COURSE_ID = CourseAttendance.COURSE_ID) 
    AND (qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.EMPLOYEE_ID = CourseAttendance.EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

This one doesnt handle the exception of No course defined –

```
Course Table:
COURSE_PK   START DATE  END DATE    COURSENAME    NOTES         LOCATION_ID  
1           12/2/2012   12/2/2012   OTC           No Notes            3  
2           12/1/2012   12/1/2012   OTC           No Note             2   
3           1/5/2012    1/5/2012    Requistions  Text Text Text       1 
                                      and P-Cards

CourseAttendance Table:
COURSEATTENDANCE_PK COURSE_ID   EMPLOYEE_ID  
1                   1               1  
2                   2               2  

CourseRole Table:
COURSEROLE_PK   COURSE_ID   ROLE_ID  
1                   1         1  
2                   1         2  
3                   1         3  
4                   2         1  
5                   2         2  

Employee Table:
EMPLOYEE_PK EMPLOYEE_LAST   EMPLOYEE_FIRST  EMPLOYEE_USERID  
1              Ables        Christopher        LG854  
2              Ables        Gary               LC876  
3              Ables        Steven             LQ875  

EmployeeRole Table:
EMPLOYEEROLE_PK EMPLOYEE_ID ROLE_ID  
1                     1         1  
2                     1         2  
3                     1         3  
4                     2         1  
5                     2         2  
6                     3         4  

Location Table:
LOCATION_PK LOCATION  
1             New York  
2             New Brunfels  
3             Ontario  
4             China  

Role Table:
ROLE_PK ROLENAME  
1             Service Coordinator    
2             Service Planner  
3             Service Entry  
4             AP Invoice  

Trainer Table:
TRAINER_PK  TRAINER_LAST    TRAINER_FIRST   TRAINER_USERID  
1              Brunet              Janell     
2              Gibson              Jim             hb476  
3              Taylor              Diana           hblo7hg  

TrainerCourse Table:
TRAINERCOURSE_PK    TRAINER_ID  COURSE_ID  
1                     1         1  
2                     1         2  
3                     2         2
```

Now that i've walked through the logic in this much detail it appears this will require more than just a fancy query.  If you need me to be more specific I can be but it's going to require me to upload a document or something.

All Queries I've created and Reason for Query:

```
 EmployeeCourseOutsideofRole
 SELECT CourseAttendance.EMPLOYEE_ID, CourseAttendance.COURSE_ID, Course.COURSE_NAME  
 FROM Course INNER JOIN (CourseAttendance LEFT JOIN qryEmployeeCoursesForRole ON  
 (CourseAttendance.COURSE_ID = qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.COURSE_ID) AND  
 (CourseAttendance.EMPLOYEE_ID = qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.EMPLOYEE_ID)) ON Course.COURSE_PK =  
 CourseAttendance.COURSE_ID
 WHERE (((qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.EMPLOYEE_ID) Is Null) AND     
 ((qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.COURSE_ID)  
 Is Null)); 
 If Employee took a Course and the CourseRole not equal to EmployeeRole
```

---

```
 EmployeeCoursesForRoleSub:
 SELECT [Employee_last] & " " & [employee_first] AS FullName, Role.ROLENAME,  
 EmployeeRole.EMPLOYEE_ID, EmployeeRole.ROLE_ID  
 FROM Role INNER JOIN (Employee INNER JOIN EmployeeRole ON Employee.EMPLOYEE_PK =  
 EmployeeRole.EMPLOYEE_ID) ON Role.ROLE_PK = EmployeeRole.ROLE_ID;
 This is a SubQuery only--for next
```

---

```
 qryEmployeeCourseForRole:
 SELECT qryEmployeeCoursesForRoleSub.*, CourseRole.COURSE_ID  
 FROM qryEmployeeCoursesForRoleSub LEFT JOIN CourseRole ON qryEmployeeCoursesForRoleSub.ROLE_ID =  
 CourseRole.ROLE_ID;
 This shows courserole with matching employeerole--a subquery for next
```

---

```
 EmployeeCourseForRoleWAttended:  
 SELECT qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.*, IIf(IsNull([courseattendance_PK]),"No","Yes") AS Attended  
 FROM qryEmployeeCoursesForRole LEFT JOIN CourseAttendance ON (qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.COURSE_ID =  
 CourseAttendance.COURSE_ID) AND (qryEmployeeCoursesForRole.EMPLOYEE_ID =  
 CourseAttendance.EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

---

Additional Sample data for debugging

```
 Employee Table: 
 Employee_PK     Employee_Last     Employee_First  
 Autonumber       Daigle             Jake
 Autonumber       Ryder              Canen  

 Role Table:
 Role_PK    RoleName  
  5            Asset Shipper
  6            Material Controller  
  7            Material MAnager  

 EmployeeRole Table:  
 EmployeeRole_PK     Employee_ID         Role_ID  
 Autonum              Whatever Daigle is       5  
 Autonum              Whatever Daigle is       1  
 Autonum              Whatever Ryder is        5
 Autonum              Whatever Ryder is        6    

 Course Table:             
 Course_PK    Course_Name  Course_StartDate  Course_EndDate  
   4           OTC           12/8/2011        12/9/2011  

 CourseRole Table:  
 CourseRole_PK   Course_ID      Role _ID   
   6               4              1 
   7               4              7  

 CourseAttendance:
 CourseAttendance_PK      Course_ID      Employee_ID
  Autonum                  4              Whatever Daigle is
  Autonum                  4              Whatever Ryder is
```

---

Ok I posted the sample data.  The problem occurs if a user has attended a course that fulfills one of their roles and the courserole = employeerole then the query is reporting that they have fulfilled ALL of their roles.

What I need in a single report:

Employee Last Name, Employee First Name, Role 1, CoureName, Start Date, End Date, Attended
But the logic will need to be there as I have it listed above at the beginning of the post.

Comment: there are some discrepancies in your tables.  first, you have in EmployeeRole a field called Role_ID is that Role_PK in your Role table?  Also in you EmployeeRole table is Employee_ID the Employee_PK or Employee_userid in your Employee table?

Comment: editing your question and posting some sample data would be helpful

Comment: Mostly when people say sample data, they mean small sections of the relevant tables cut and pasted to the question.

Comment: @Piercy yes posting actual data is helpful

Comment: in the query you posted you have IIf(IsNull([courseattendance_PK]),"No","Yes") but in your table you have courseattendance_PK as 1 or 2 and if it is a Primary Key is cannot be null. so it is impossible to tell what is yes or no by this.

Comment: So the Query listed above is using a SubQuery which was not using referential integrity. The Yes, No system did work but it did not help me if the course didnt have a specific role and because referential integrity wasn't enabled the data was hard to deal with on a large scale.  --Based on what I have shown above, how can I create the logic and report I need?  Do I need to code the logic?  If so, how would I go about generating a qury/report based on the logic?  I've never gone through that process.

Comment: so are you saying that if there is a record in the course attendance table, that means Yes they attended it.  You are looking for logic based on the attendance = Yes or No but it is not clear what this table is doing.

Comment: the CourseAttendance table itself is the record of if they have attended. If the record is in the CourseAttendance table it means they've attended. I realize what you are saying that there would not be an entry in the table if they didnt -- but in that case couldnt we determine that no they did not attend? But it would be using a different parameter.---I created about a half dozen or so queries that Pull some of the information.  I can post those and give an explanation of why they aren't working.

Comment: based on the sample data above, can you edit the question with the result you are hoping for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its kind of messy but this should get you started.  Based on the table structures you have above, your design is a bit off. You have tables with unnecessary columns but that wasn't your question.

This can be split into 3 different queries or just use a `UNION` as I did below:

```
'this first query gets you the employees who have attended
SELECT E.EmployeeLast, E.EmployeeFirst, R.RoleName AS EmployeeRole
    , C.CourseName, C.StartDate, C.EndDate, "Yes" AS Attended
FROM (((Employee AS E 
INNER JOIN EmployeeRole AS ER 
    ON E.EmployeePK=ER.EmployeeId) 
INNER JOIN Role AS R 
    ON ER.RoleID=R.RolePK) 
LEFT JOIN CourseAttendance AS CA 
    ON E.EmployeePK=CA.EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN Course AS C 
    ON CA.CourseID=C.CoursePK
WHERE E.EmployeePK IN (SELECT CA.EmployeeID 
                        FROM ((CourseAttendance CA 
                        INNER JOIN EmployeeRole ER 
                            ON CA.EmployeeId = ER.EmployeeId) 
                        INNER JOIN CourseRole CR 
                            ON ER.RoleId = CR.RoleId 
                            AND CA.CourseID = CR.CourseID));

UNION

'this second query gets you the employees who have not attended
SELECT E.EmployeeLast, E.EmployeeFirst, R.RoleName AS EmployeeRole
    , C.CourseName, C.StartDate, C.EndDate, "No" AS Attended
FROM (((Employee AS E 
INNER JOIN EmployeeRole AS ER 
    ON E.EmployeePK=ER.EmployeeId) 
INNER JOIN Role AS R 
    ON ER.RoleID=R.RolePK) 
LEFT JOIN CourseAttendance AS CA 
    ON E.EmployeePK=CA.EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN Course AS C 
    ON CA.CourseID=C.CoursePK
WHERE E.EmployeePK NOT IN (SELECT CA.EmployeeID 
                        FROM ((CourseAttendance CA 
                        INNER JOIN EmployeeRole ER 
                            ON CA.EmployeeId = ER.EmployeeId) 
                        INNER JOIN CourseRole CR 
                            ON ER.RoleId = CR.RoleId 
                            AND CA.CourseID = CR.CourseID));

UNION

'this final query gets you the employees who have not attended and there is no course with their role
SELECT E.EmployeeLast, E.EmployeeFirst, R.RoleName AS EmployeeRole
    , C.CourseName, C.StartDate, C.EndDate, "No Course With Role" AS Attended
FROM (((Employee AS E 
INNER JOIN EmployeeRole AS ER 
    ON E.EmployeePK=ER.EmployeeId) 
INNER JOIN Role AS R 
    ON ER.RoleID=R.RolePK) 
LEFT JOIN CourseAttendance AS CA 
    ON E.EmployeePK=CA.EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN Course AS C 
    ON CA.CourseID=C.CoursePK
WHERE ER.RoleID NOT IN (SELECT RoleID 
                        FROM CourseRole)
    AND E.EmployeePK NOT IN  (SELECT CA.EmployeeID 
                                FROM ((CourseAttendance CA 
                                INNER JOIN EmployeeRole ER 
                                    ON CA.EmployeeId = ER.EmployeeId) 
                                INNER JOIN CourseRole CR 
                                    ON ER.RoleId = CR.RoleId 
                                    AND CA.CourseID = CR.CourseID));
```

Comment: I'm going to attempt this now.  Will report back after I edit the script to fit my DB

Comment: BlueFeet...I am thoroughly impressed.  On my test database that I had to create to get you sample data it is working as desired.  I am going to move this to my staging database and try it out.  I'll report back. I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: ok I think there may be an issue with the first query. When I dumped this into my Staging database which has more realistic data then I filtered the results to just 1 role(this role has No Course Defined). It's reporting that some people have attended=Yes for this role and others as "No Course with role." Any thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing all of the data it is difficult.  As I said, the query I gave you is a starting point. You will probably need to fine tune it to your needs.  If you provided more sample data I could probably attempt to debug, but based on the data you provided I was able to get the results you wanted.

Comment: Yes you did. I'm going to dump more data into my test database.  There may be some bad values. I'll report back after I complete. Thank you

Comment: Ok. I have tested this now with live data.  There is something wrong with Qry 1 where Attended = Yes.  It is reporting that someone has attended a course with a role, but there is no course defnied for that role.  I'll need to post more data and I'll try to debug the issue in the morning. Thank you for the help thus far though

Comment: you will have to post more data then. based on the data you posted yesterday the query works.

Comment: I posted the additional sample data and my findings when I was debugging just below the sample data.

Comment: Attended = Yes for that one record if EmployeeRole = CourseRole but if EmployeeRole <> CourseRole then No they haven't attended or next possible logic is No Course Defined.  Do I need to rewrite the logic statement tat the top, I was thinking that was implied to iterate through.

Comment: your new request is different from the OP.  In you original post you asked if they attended when employeerole = courserole not where employeerole = all of their courseroles.  That is a different question.  My answer solved your original question.  If you need more help with a different query, then it would be a different question.

Comment: Yes you answered the question but the question I was asking did not give you as much details as you needed.  So I can recreate the question and edit the logic to be more specific or I can edit it here.  I'm not sure I see the purpose of the first though.  Whatever you prefer, you've been a major help to me, so I do not care.

Comment: This query ended up helping me get to a solution.  It performed the OP logic